# How to start working with tex core?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I've been programming, writing articles and presentations on LaTeX for couple of years; and made few tutorials about starting working with latex, adjusting properties to write on Georgian, drawing 2D/3D images with tikz...

Now, I want to start working with its core, writing commands, adjusting styles, without relying (so much) on prewritten packages.

Can anyone advise, how and from where can I start?

Comment: I'm not clear if you mean writing stuff in plain TeX or programming LaTeX at a lower level: could you clarify?

Comment: Programming LaTeX at a lower level

Comment: If you are looking for programming, the perhaps this one? [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TeX core starting points

- Donald E. Knuth (author of TeX): The TeXbook
- Victor Eijkhout: [TeX by Topic](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic)
- Norbert Schwarz: [Einführung in TeX](http://www.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/schwarz/TeX/einfuehrung-in-tex.pdf)<sup>1</sup> (German)

<sup>1</sup> According to the preface, the PDF version was made available by the author.

### Extensions to TeX

- The NTS team: [The e-TeX manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf)
- Hàn Thế Thành, Sebastian Rahtz, Hans Hagen et al.: [The pdfTeX user manual](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/doc/pdftex/manual)
- LuaTeX development team: [LuaTeX reference manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/luatex/luatex.pdf)
- Jonathan Kew: [About XeTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/xetex/XeTeX-notes.pdf)
- Will Robertson, Khaled Hosney: T[he XeTeX reference guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf)

### LaTeX documentation

- The basic LaTeX documentation should be installed with LaTeX. Documentation directory<sup>2</sup>:

  ```
  TDS:doc/latex/base/
  ```

  It contains user guides and also the documented source code (`source2e.pdf`).

<sup>2</sup> TDS = [TeX Directory Structure](http://ctan.org/pkg/tds)

Comment: (+1). I find Martin Scharrer's *List of internal LaTeX2e Macros useful to Package Authors* (`texdoc macros2e`) useful as well (not in the `base` directory).